# Agregar icono fa en una caja de texto

Tags: bootstrap

Buena tarde tengo el siguiente codigo html, estoy usando bootstrap 4

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
<span class="fa fa-user form-control-feedback"></span>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Escribe un nombre">
</div>
```

Lo que quiero hacer es colocar iconos adentro de la caja de texto, pero no he podido solucionar esto, como lo podría hacer??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para añadir iconos en **bootstrap 4**, incluya la referencia de **Font Awesome** *(ya sea localmente, o use el CDN).*

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

> **Nota:** Si estás realizando una migración anterior/posterior por la actual, realice una búsqueda y reemplace esto `"glyphicon glyphicon-"` y reemplácelo por `"fa fa-"`. La mayoría de los nombres de las clase `CSS` de los iconos son iguales. ***Sin embargo, algunos han cambiado, por lo que debes corregirlos manualmente.***

O si aún desean utilizar los iconos de **Glyphicons**. El archivo glyphicons.less de Bootstrap 3 está disponible en [GitHub](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/glyphicons.less).

Luego se necesitan de las siguientes variables:

```
@icon-font-path:          "../fonts/";
@icon-font-name:          "glyphicons-halflings-regular";
@icon-font-svg-id:        "glyphicons_halflingsregular";
```

Ahora tocaría convertir el archivo `.less` en un archivo `.css` para luego así usarlo directamente. La migración `.less` a  `.css` podemos hacer uso de la siguiente herramienta en línea [less2css.org](http://less2css.org/), de gran utiidad. Y así obtendremos el siguiente [resultado](https://pastebin.com/7WFcBn0f), guárde el archivo como `glyphicons.css` y listo ya lo puede incluir en sus archivos `HTML`.

```
<link href="/Content/glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

También se necesitan las fuentes **Glyphicon** que se encuentran en el paquete Bootstrap 3, coloquelas en el/un directorio `/ fonts /`.

> Ahora puedes seguir usando `Glyphicons` en **Bootstrap 4** como de costumbre.

**Ejemplo actual versión Bootstrap 4**

```css
.form-control-feedback {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.form-control {
  padding-left: 30px!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="form-group has-feedback">
  <i class="fa fa-user form-control-feedback"></i>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Escribe un nombre">
</div>
```

Más referencia de migración en la siguiente [fuente.](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/)

Comment: Gracias amigo me ayudo lo que compartiste, gracias!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Buenas amigo espero esto sea lo que buscas saludos es solo css sin usar bootstrap

Respuesta con la ayuda de [gugadev](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/26302/gugadev)

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700";
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 1rem;
}

#search-wrapper {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  display: -webkit-inline-flex;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: inline-flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row-reverse nowrap;
      -ms-flex-flow: row-reverse nowrap;
          flex-flow: row-reverse nowrap;
  width: 350px;
}
#search-wrapper #search {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-left: 0;
  border-radius: 0 25px 25px 0;
  color: #444;
  padding: .6rem .5rem;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  -webkit-transition: border-color .2s ease;
  transition: border-color .2s ease;
  width: 100%;
}
#search-wrapper #search + i {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 25px 0 0 25px;
  border-right: 0;
  color: #777;
  padding: .67rem .65rem;
  -webkit-transition: border-color .2s ease;
  transition: border-color .2s ease;
}
#search-wrapper #search:focus {
  border-color: #999;
  outline: none;
}
#search-wrapper #search:focus + i {
  border-color: #999;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="search-wrapper">
  <input 
         type="search" 
         id="search" 
         placeholder="Buscar"
   />
  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer asi...

`<a href="https://complementosparati.com/" class="headerLink" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-shopping-bag fa-fw" style="font-size:48px;color:#337ab7;position: relative;top: 18px;"><p style="font-size: 11px;color: #fff;position: relative;top: -11px;left: 0px;"><b>Tienda</b></p></i></a>`

El texto se queda debajo o en medio como prefieras

o bien de este modo

`````
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<a href="https://misydia.com/" class="headerLink" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-shopping-bag fa-fw" style="font-size:48px;color:#337ab7;position: relative;top: 18px;"><p style="font-size: 11px;color: #000;position: relative;top: -35px;left: 0px;"><b>Tienda</b></p></i></a>

</body>
</html>````
`````